# ZeroAllocation Hash library vs Murmur3Hash

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hash

I need to hash short strings using a fast hash function. At the moment i use the *StringHash* function from the *Murmur3Hash* provided in the *scala.utils* package.

I thought about using the *xxHash* from the zero allocation library for java/scala, since it is stated that it is much faster and has the same quality as *Murmur3Hash*:
https://github.com/OpenHFT/Zero-Allocation-Hashing

1. Is it significantly faster than Murmur3Hash in practice for strings?
2. At the moment i use 32-bit values, since its the output from the *StringHash* function, and it suffices my needs. The *xxHash* function works on 64-bit values. While space is no issue here, is the performance difference between 32-bit and 64-bit values big ?

While there is surely an answer scattered across the internet, i was not able to gather an definite answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not test this and see?